# how to run PowerShell code from React Component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, powershell

I am new to React and Nodejs and was wondering how I can run a Powershell script from an import form in a react component.  I know react is a front end framework and it's actually Nodejs that needs to call the script but I am having a hard time trying to get it to work.

My research has lead me to use node-powershell but I can't find an example that won't crash.  I can't get it to render.

How can i get this to render in a functional component.

```
import { PowerShell } from 'node-powershell'

function RunPowerShell() {
    const ps = new PowerShell({
        executableOptions: {
        '-ExecutionPolicy': 'Bypass',
        '-NoProfile': true,
        },
    });

    const scriptCommand = PowerShell.command`Get-Service`;
    const result = ps.invoke(scriptCommand);
    console.log(result);

    return (
        <>
            {result}
        </>
    )
}

export default RunPowerShell
```

Comment: As you have already pointed out, React will be running on the front end, to run a PowerShell script you would need to post back the script you wish to run to your server side and get the server to run it. `node-powershell` is most likely only runnable for a `node` target and not runnable for a `browser` target.